# Retrieve url param value from strapi

Tags: strapi, url-parameters

How do I get the parameters value passed in the url? For example, my url is `/forgot-password?email=testing@example.com&token=fb49d692186dd4744af50446fad2f031`

I want to get the value of email and token. All I found from the doc is only about the segment as parameters value which set from route as `/user/:id` which is different usage for my case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strapi uses [koa](https://koajs.com/).
Therefor you can just use `ctx.request.query`.
Inside your handler:

```
async test(ctx) {
  let queryObj = ctx.request.query
  //use them...
}
```

For your stated request the object will contain:

```
{
  email: 'testing@example.com',
  token: 'fb49d692186dd4744af50446fad2f031'
}
```

Comment: Related but not what you asked: be careful when sending private/sensitive data in url query - https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29598/should-sensitive-data-ever-be-passed-in-the-query-string 
https://owasp.org/www-community/vulnerabilities/Information_exposure_through_query_strings_in_url#:~:text=Information%20exposure%20through%20query%20strings%20in%20URL%20is%20when%20sensitive,does%20not%20resolve%20this%20vulnerability.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the information. That was helpful.